# Facebook login winforms

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms

Here is my generate URL:

```
private Uri GenerateLoginUrl(string appId, string extendedPermissions)
{
    // for .net 3.5
    // var parameters = new Dictionary<string,object>
    // parameters["client_id"] = appId;
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.client_id = appId;
    parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

    // The requested response: an access token (token), an authorization code (code), or both (code token).
    parameters.response_type = "token";

    // list of additional display modes can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display
    parameters.display = "popup";

    //scope
    parameters.scope = "Email";

    // add the 'scope' parameter only if we have extendedPermissions.
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extendedPermissions))
        parameters.scope = extendedPermissions;

    // when the Form is loaded navigate to the login url.
    return _fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
   //webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("www.facebook.com"));

}
```

The problem is the `return _fb.GetLoginUrl` is `NULL`. I have a `webBrowser` control already on the WinForm.

Any ideas? or can i just hard code the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Worked at this a few months ago. I had the same problem cause by the ajax in the response site. The problem is that the ajax load the site content after the url is loaded. I fixed it by wait for the webbrowseres load event.   I think it was `webrowser.DocumentCompleted`
I hope this help you.

Comment: I am using winforms, `webBrowser.DocumentLoaded` doesnt exist!

Comment: try DocumentCompleted event